# Comparison of grades of students and Coins distributions

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm stuck at this. I`m beginner into software development. You get a list of N students and then a list of ratings for each student. A student which has bigger rating than his neighbour from list gets more coins than both of them. For example:

Data input:

- 3
- John
- Dan
- Sam
- 9
- 10
- 8

Data output:

- John 1
- Dan 3
- Sam 1

My output is just the names of the students.

I wrote this code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        var numberCoins = new int[n];
        string[] studentNames = new string[n];
        numberCoins[0] = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            studentNames[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        int[] grades = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            grades[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (grades[i] > grades[i - 1])
            {
                numberCoins[i] = numberCoins[i - 1] + 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (grades[i] > grades[i + 1])
            {
                numberCoins[i] = numberCoins[i + 1] + 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(studentNames[i], " ", numberCoins[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: your data input does not make much sense you say you get a list of n students first but your input starts with  a rating 3 whose it for?  who does the 9, 10, and 8 go with?

Comment: What problem are you having? If you remove the initial 3 then your input lines up.

Comment: 3 is the N (number of students/number of grades), 9, 10, 8 are the grades for those students.

Comment: Just a note regarding the `Console.WriteLine()`: You are probably executing [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-6.0#system-console-writeline(system-string-system-object-system-object)), which is why the grades are not being printed. (In fact, not even the space is being printed). Try `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", studentNames[i], numberCoins[i]);` (same overload) or `Console.WriteLine(studentNames[i] + " " + numberCoins[i]);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if there is any pattern to give coins to the students. And if we have specific number of coins or not.

If we consider at first no one has any coins the result must be something like the following:

```plaintext
Please specify the number of the students:
3

Please write students' name (after each name hit the ENTER):
John
Dan
Sam

Please write students' ratings (after each rating hit the ENTER):
9
10
8

The result:
John: 0
Dan: 2
Sam: 0
```

I wrote a piece of code which might help you approach the functionality you want.

```cs
using System;
    
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please specify the number of the students:");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        string[] studentNames = new string[n];
        int[] studentRatings = new int[n];
        int[] studentCoins = new int[n];

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please write students' name (after each name hit the ENTER):");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            studentNames[i] = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please write students' ratings (after each rating hit the ENTER):");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            studentRatings[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The result:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int coins = 1;
            studentCoins[i] = 0;
            
            if (i != 0)
                if (studentRatings[i] > studentRatings[i - 1])
                    coins++;
            
            if (i != n - 1)
                if (studentRatings[i] > studentRatings[i + 1])
                    coins++;

            studentCoins[i] = coins;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{studentNames[i]}: {studentCoins[i]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every student has a least 1 coin,  I forgot to mention that. Nice approach!

Comment: I refactored the `for` block which operates over `studentCoins` calculation. It now specifies 1 coin for every student as default, So the result will be the following: `John: 0, Dan: 2 and Sam: 0`